# Button in CustomControl added in OnClick doesn't postback until second click

Tags: asp.net, .net, updatepanel, postback

I have the following scenario:

1. `UserControlA` contains a `<asp:Button id="bSomeid" onClick="AddItem" />` with some code to an item to a shopping basket in `AddItem`.
2. `UserControlB` contains some `LinkButton`'s that dynamically add a selection of `UserControlA` to the page in the `OnClick` event.

This is all done in an `UpdatePanel`. It is a little more complicated but I have pruned the information to what I believe is causing the problem, I will add more information if necessary.

The problem I have is that it takes 2 clicks for the `AddItem` event to trigger after I have added the items to the page after clicking the `LinkButton`.

I understand why this is happening - it is to late in the page cycle to register events for the next post back in the onclick - but can anyone think of a way around this? Can I force an event to be triggered on the next postback? I have tried to think of a way to run my code in `page_load` but I requuire access to the `sender` in the `onClick`.

Using .NET 4.0.

**EDIT**

I managed to find a way to get the link button sending the request in the Page_Load (using `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];`) so I moved my code to the `Page_load` event. It still requires 2 clicks so I am assuming it isn't something to do with the onClick being registered to late.

Are there any other general things to check that could cause a button to require 2 clicks to post an event properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your suspicion about being late in page life cycle is true then you can try using [ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method to register dynamically added controls in the link button click - considering that your button is within user control, you need to add public method into `UserControlA` that would actually register the button `bSomeid1` and link button click from `UserControlB` would actually call the A control's method.

**EDIT** :

Another cause for button click not happening can be that button being dynamic control is not added in the page hierarchy when post-back happens (or it gets added very late in the page life cycle when the post back data is already processed). A really full-proof solution should add dynamic controls back to the page hierarchy in `page_load` it-self (and strictly maintaining same controls ids within hierarchy). If that's not possible then you can sniff the request (`Request.Form`) to detect the post-back.

In your case, you should ascertain if the button is indeed causing the post-back on each click. If yes, what is the POST data (`Request.Form`) for the first request - what is the __EVENTTARGET value on the first click (and post-back)? That should start your trouble-shooting.

On the other hand, a simple work-around could be to use html anchor element (you can still use link button) and have a javascript handler in the click event that would set some hidden variable and then submit the form (you can simulate the click on hidden button to trigger ASP.NET client side submit pipeline) . Now the hidden variable value can be used on the post-back to determine which link button has been clicked.

Comment: I tried this but it still required 2 clicks. I also tried moving my code to the page_load and it still required 2 clicks. I assume that something else is wrong then. Any rough ideas what would cause a button to have 2 clicks to fire an event?

Answer (score 0):

> "Are there any other general things to check that could cause a button to require 2 clicks to post an event properly?"

Does it require two clicks on the control, or does it take accept a single click elsewhere on the screen, and then fire first time with a single click on the control?

I have my own (similar) issue with the Updatepanel where the first (expected) trigger does not fire and it seems that a single click elsewhere, and then the subsequent triggers fires first time (which totals 2 clicks)

[edit] Since you are working on this ATM, it may help me as well. Do you have a textbox with a trigger event on it? I do, and if I leave this blank (so that it does not fire) then there is no need for a second click.